# Error when setting self-defined storyboard as main interface

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So I deleted main.Storyboard and defined a new storyboard file named Test.storyboard. I also set it as the main interface of the app in the target's general settings. When I ran it, the following error was produced:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIStoryboard initWithBundle:storyboardFileName:identifierToNibNameMap:designatedEntryPointIdentifier:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44/UIStoryboard.m:52

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid parameter not satisfying: nibNameMap != nil'
```

Anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have to pick a view controller and set it as the initial view controller by ticking "Is Initial View Controller" in the storyboard